# OpenCart: Get $this->session->data['order_id'] in module before ControllerCheckoutSuccess class unsets it

Tags: php, session, opencart

I am developing an OpenCart module and struggling with getting the order_id by using `$this->session->data['order_id']`.

My module is working fine if I comment out the part which unsets the order_id session variable in `ControllerCheckoutSuccess` class.

How can I ensure that I get the order_id before `ControllerCheckoutSuccess` unsets it?

**Edit1:** I need the order id to extract details like customer name, total amount, subtotal etc for that particular order. Is there some other method by which I can get the order id?

**Edit2:** Added this code in `'store/catalog/controller/module/myModule.php'` in `index()` function. Using it to store order_id in temp session variable and use it on order success -

```
if (isset($this->session->data['temp_order_id']) 
     && isset($this->request->get['route']) 
     && $this->request->get['route'] == 'checkout/success')
{
    // perform custom action
    unset($this->session->data['temp_order_id']);
} 
elseif (isset($this->session->data['order_id']))
{
    $this->session->data['temp_order_id'] = $this->session->data['order_id'];
}
```

Please help!

Comment: Update the question with the exact requirement. Why do you want to use the order_id after checkout success page? To ensure that you get `order_id` before `ControllerCheckoutSuccess` unsets it, you need to write code before the code that unset it.

Comment: @SankarV: Edited my question. Please check.

Comment: Why do you need to extract those details?

Comment: I am developing a referral system and I need these details for analytics part.

Comment: Can't you add a function for your requirement in checkout/success controller before the unset code?

Comment: That's the whole point. I am not developing module just for me. In that case there was no problem. It will be available to all users.

Comment: Can't we set the order_id in another session variable and use it for your requirements? Also don't forget to unset it once its use is over.

Comment: Already doing this. See the Edit2 part. But no luck!

Comment: Where did you add the above code? Update with filename and line number.

Comment: Edited in the question.

Answer (score 3):

In `catalog/controller/checkout/success.php` file, add:

`$this->session->data['temp_order_id'] = $this->session->data['order_id']`;

After:

`if (isset($this->session->data['order_id'])) {`

Then call your custom module or call your custom module before checkout success page controller is called.

Comment: How can I call my module before checkout success page controller is called?

Comment: How did you call your custom module earlier?

Comment: Layout: checkout and position: text_content_bottom.
This is being set in admin panel through module setting page.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't find any solution for this so sorted it by dynamically adding code (as mentioned by Sankar V) using vQmod. However, it adds a dependency that vQmod should be installed already.

Hope it helps someone facing similar problem.